# AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment goes into 'Severe' every time I run 'eb deploy'

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a React git project that I deployed through Docker onto an ElasticBeanstalk environment.
The first time I run `eb deploy` I don't experience any error and it deploys correctly onto ElasticBeanstalk environment. But when I change the source code, if I try to deploy it onto the same environment I get an error.

This is what I run:

```
 git add *
 git commit -am "My First Commit"
 docker build -t new-docker-version .
 eb create react-env
```

Then after the environment is created and I change the source code

```
 git add *
 git commit -am "Changed Source Code"
 docker rmi new-docker-version
 docker build -t new-docker-version .
 eb deploy
```

The 'deploy' runs approximately for 10 minutes before entering into a 'Severe' state due:

`Incorrect application version "app-f43da-200915_151515" (deployment 4). Expected version "app-7295-200915_141954" (deployment 1).`

How can I deploy an updated version of my source code into the same environment through eb cli?

Comment: Maybe there is something on your code that prevents you to deploy the application on the same beanstalk. What is shown in the eb-activity logs?

Comment: I'm surprised  to see it going to severe for that, this should only return you a warning. Look at the logs on your beanstalk instance and see what's really going on. Maybe you're deploying on the wrong one, try `eb list` and `eb use NAME` before deploying.

Comment: When checking inside eb-engine.log the only error I see is:

     [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Run Docker Container]. Stop running the command. Error: startProcess Failure: starting process "eb-docker-log" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-docker-log.service failed with error exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took quite some effort and digging, and probably there are better answers, but this is my take of it.

In order to have it working perfectly, one should not start an Elastic Beanstalk Environment from the console panel, but from the command line. The first step is to create a folder `.elasticbeanstalk` under the root of the project, and once in it creating a file `config.yml` that looks like the following:

```
branch-defaults:
  production:
    environment: my-prod
  staging:
    environment: my-dev
global:
  application_name: my_application_name
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: my_key_pair
  default_platform: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux
  default_region: my_default_region
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

After that, go back to the root of the project and run:

```
eb init
eb create my-dev
```

From now on, every change one makes can be simply pushed to the environment by running `eb deploy`.

###############################################

A second solution that I find more "industrial accurate" is the use of AWS CodePipeline.

This is the [Medium tutorial](https://medium.com/@saikat.ghosh/configure-aws-codepipeline-with-bitbucket-and-elastic-beanstalk-ad676c3a79e) I followed. Once CodePipeline is attached to the current branch of the git project repository, (and once all the steps above regarding the file `config.yml` under the folder `.elasticbeanstalk` are done), changes will be visible directly on the ELB environment simply after every git push.